# Trouble linking to gobject-introspection library

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I have the file blah.c containing:

```
#include <gobject-introspection-1.0/girepository.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    GIRepository *gir = g_irepository_get_default();
    return 0;
}
```

This, of course, is simpler than the file I wish to compile, but has the same problem. I compile with

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gobject-introspection-1.0` blah.c
```

and get the linking error:

```
/tmp/cck88oj4.o: In function `main':
blah.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `g_irepository_get_default'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The `pkg-config` command returns

```
-pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0  -Wl,--export-dynamic -pthread -lgirepository-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lffi -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0
```

and the files libgirepository-1.0.a and libgirepository-1.0.so are both present in /usr/lib.

What is causing this linking error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the linking error could be because the linker is linking with `-Wl, as-needed` option by default. When this option is used, the libraries are not linked until symbol in the library is encountered. In your current case as the source file is added in the end, none of the symbols in the libraries are encountered, thus linking is not done. You could try:

```
gcc blah.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gobject-introspection-1.0`
```

or

```
gcc -Wl,-no-as-needed `pkg-config --cflags --libs gobject-introspection-1.0` blah.c
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you! I don't have the necessary reputation to upvote your answer, but I would if I could.

Comment: @MichaelSiler: Glad to help! This problem has been seen quite a few times. Well you have accepted the answer I guess that is enough & more importantly it fixed your problem :)